# Authenticate in IBM WebSphere Portal using Facebook API

Tags: java, websphere-portal, ibm-was

I have IBM WebSphere Portal and IBM WebSphere Application Server for sure. Login into WPS use IBM WAS, which use IBM Tivoli Directory Server. And now i want to implement one more button, which let me authenticate user in WPS using Facebook account (for a example). Which way i have to choose? Use JAAS? Or something else? I want to maximize the use of internal mechanisms of IBM WAS Security.

Comment: I am not sure, but take a look on this http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYJ99_8.5.0/security/use_social.dita

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the link given in the comment you could write your own authentication writing your own [Trusted Association Interceptor](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0508_benantar/0508_benantar.html). Implementing OAuth with the given TAI is however probably way more easier.

Comment: Which version of Portal/WAS i have to install? I have WAS 6.1 and WSP 6.1.0.5.

Comment: All logic with facebook api i have to implement inside TAI?

Comment: The comment was on 8.5. If you are starting with a fresh project make sure you use 8.5. 6.1.x is out of support. If you implement it yourself, TAI already has been within the product for quite a long time.

Comment: I dont understand. Now i'm trying to implement auth with Google or Facebook using new features in IBM WebSphere Portal 8.0 and IBM WAS 8.5.5. There are not only TAI, there Login Portlet changes (to show Buttons such as Sign in using Google and etc), but you told me that i can just write my own TAI and that's it. Please help with right way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it custom you will not get around TAI. TAI does allow you to send the user to Facebook for the authentication challenge using the TAIResult responsecode 302 in addition to setting the redirect on the Response object.
If you want to reuse available options you should have a look at the extension Portal added to its code. It includes an extension to the default login Portlet and the ability to have Facebook users not required inside of the Portal userbase. It is called transient

just for reference 
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/dx/How_to_Configure_and_Use_OpenID_Facebook_integration_on_WebSphere_Portal